# In Elden Ring, are the summoning pools working with multiplayer password?

Tags: elden-ring

I'm in a big group of players, and I want to being able to be summoned easily.
So I entered the group multiplayer password, and I was wondering if the summoning pools are functional ?

Or can I only use my summoning sign on the floor.